# Find | grep doesn't work in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, grep, find

I have cygwin installed and when I search for the source code with this command nothing show up, even that I have that string in a file

```
$ echo foo > bar
$ find . -name '*' | grep foo
```

Nothing shows up. This command works fine on GNU+Linux.

```
$ grep foo bar
```

Comment: Could also pipe find to xargs, as in `$ find . | xargs grep foo`

Comment: @Xen2050 you can add that as an answer, I forget xargs.

Comment: @jcubic You don't need to use `find` at all. See my answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does `$ which find` return on Cygwin?

Comment: @SalvoF `/usr/bin/find`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, find outputs a list of found files to stdout, grep normally expects to search through stdout if called this way.

Could also pipe find to `xargs`, and it will "*build and execute command lines from standard input*", as in

```
$ find . | xargs grep foo
```

If you have crazy filenames, with newlines and whatnot, then this would be better:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep foo
```

and the `-type f` will only find regular files, so no attempts to grep through any `.` or `..` or any directories or "funny" files.

Comment: That is messy output (lines like `grep: .: Is a directory
` and `grep: ./test: Is a directory`. You might consider adding `--exclude-dir=*` to `grep`. Or just use `grep --exclude-dir=* "foo" ./*` as per my answer ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill I was going to add the `-type f` tag in there, I always use it in these situations, but I was sticking with the general format in the question & other answers. I'll add it in though

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -name  '*' # This will produce a list of *file names*
```

You then pass your list of filenames to `grep` on stdin, it treats the list as text and searches for `foo`

You have no file name of `foo` so it returns nothing.

To search recursively through files looking for text in a file you can simply use

```
grep -R foo somefolder/
```

Comment: find | grep work on linux

Comment: @jcubic if your command `find . -name '*' | grep foo` find the word foo inside  of the files listed by the find command then your Linux is broken and you should file a bug.

Comment: @stemartin I have a theory: A recent GNU grep + `alias grep="grep -r"` you get that behaviour, since GNU Coreutils developers in their great wisdom decided that `grep -r` on STDIN makes no sense and instead we will silently fix it to grep the current directory. I personally consider that behaviour a major bug.

Answer (score 2):

#### When I search for the source code with this command nothing shows up

```
$ echo foo > bar
$ find . -name '*' | grep foo
```

`find` searches for filenames that meet a desired criteria: Name, Size, File Type and returns a list of matching filenames. It doesn't return the **contents** of the matching files.

When that list of filenames is passed to `grep` using the pipe operator `grep` will see the string `bar` (the filename) and **not** `foo` (the contents of file `bar`).

`grep` therefore doesn't find a match so has nothing to output.

Note:

- `grep` can search files directly. You don't need to use `find`. pipes `|`, or `xargs` as suggested in another answer.

The following command works on Cygwin:

```
grep --exclude-dir=* "foo" ./*
```

Example:

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ cat bar
foo

DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ grep --exclude-dir=* "foo" ./*
./bar:foo
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [find](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html) - Search a folder hierarchy for filename(s) that meet a desired criteria: Name, Size, File Type.
- [grep](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) - Search file(s) for specific text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this.

```
find . -name '*' -type f -exec grep foo /dev/null {} \;
```

You only want to grep files, not directories or special files. The /dev/null makes grep show the file name. You may want to get rid of '-name '*', but if you do, then dot files will be grepped.

You could also run

```
grep -r foo .
```

Comment: Your first command is much slower than my solution of  `grep --exclude-dir=* "foo" ./*` which produces identical output.

Comment: `grep -r foo .` can be shortened to `grep -r foo`

Comment: @DavidPostill Only on recent versions of GNU grep. It's braindead behaviour IMHO.

Comment: @oals Oh. I didn't know that. Thanks.